# LinearLayout with oval form in center

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

How i can draw a view(dark view) like in picture below?
with oval form in the center.

TextView[Transfer] - ImageView[QR Scan] (with oval form) - TextView[Request]

[image]

Comment: do you try with a background image for the same?

Comment: that is just a static background image I think

Comment: It can be possible through static background image and Relative layout for overlap.

Comment: @ParthPatel can you show an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:text="Text1"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FAFAFA"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:text="Text1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Output]